# Software control program

Tags: c++, version-control

I'm a college student majoring in computer engineering. I'm doing a c++ project in my comp sci class with 3 other people. Instead of zipping up our code and sending it to each other, what's the best software I can use for version control. I live on campus so setting up a server might be a problem (have to use university wifi). I've heard git and svn but I'm not super computer savy so command line things might confuse me.

Comment: https://github.com/ . I find this `command line things might confuse` and this `student majoring in computer engineering` in the same sentence to be very funny.

Comment: It's easy to make typos.  I prefer GUI as well.  The command line is definitely intimidating.  http://bash.org/?464385

Answer (score 6):

Use a free online source repository, such as unfuddle.com, github.com, beanstalk.com. It'll let you use either SVN or git. Some force you to have an open source project (github), others let you make it private. Also, 
both of these programs (SVN or git) have GUI front-ends, you don't have to use the command line.

Comment: To a new git user on Windows, I'd recommend [GitExtensions]( http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/ ) – it's a batteries-included frontend that will set everything up automagically.

Comment: You forgot bitbucket! It supports both git and hg now!

Answer (score 5):

I would still recommend git, simply because of the number of people working on the project, and because its good practice. But you don't have to work from the command line. There are graphical user interfaces to Git for both windows and linux.

Tutorials:

- http://progit.org/

Windows:

- https://tortoisegit.org/
- http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

Linux:

- gitk
- giggle
- git-gui
- numerous others, search in your distro's package repository

Answer (score 4):

I like [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/), which is similar in many ways to Git.

It has a GUI [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), though I have never used it.

It has free hosting at [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

Plus, in a pinch, you can just run `hg serve` to share your code over the network, which can be handy.

Gotta counterbalance all those "Use Git" answers (:

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say this but if you're majoring in computer engineering and you're not computer savvy or command line things tend to confuse you, you may have chosen the wrong career path.

Edit: OK, so I guess... I use [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/home). Free Subversion hosting and you can use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) or some other similar GUI tool.

Failing that you can use a service like Dropbox or box.net to share the code in zip files or something...

Good luck.

Comment: I'd vote that up (as I agree), but it does not answer the question. More of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Edited before your response to provide an answer, much as I didn't want to.

Comment: -1: Everybody has to start somewhere. There is a lot to learn, and so many ways to learn it. At least advice is being asked for, otherwise it's Catch 22 all over again. Using an on-line Git repo is a good solution and, assuming their older zips are available, they can have instant history and branches by importing them.

Comment: The 'please solve my problem but keep it simple because shiny things distract me' attitude is pretty crappy if you ask me. But whatever.